# Leontief utility function

Tags: multi-objective-optimization

For the Leontief utility function $$u_L(\lambda,y)=\min\{\lambda_1(r_1-y_1),\ldots,\lambda_m(r_m-y_m)\}$$

I would like to graphically show that, for $m=2$ and $\lambda\in\Lambda$ (for positive instances), not every global minimum point of L(λ) is an efficient point (Pareto optimal).

I tried to make a graph with

$u_L((1/2,1/2),.)$ and $r=[(20,15)]^T$ and got this graph

[image]

but was stuck with the proof.

Comment: What is $L(\lambda)$?